# How to stop routing to the given route if validation fails

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In my signup.ejs file, I have setup a form with post request and i have written /welcome route in signup.js file, I am trying to figure out how i can stop the post request to the given route if validation fails or how i can dynamically assign a different route like an error route (`localhost:3000/signup/error` instead of `localhost:3000/signup/welcome` if validation fails) as everytime signup fails, it is routing to `localhost:3000/signup/welcome` which is not right. I tried setting up variables in signup.ejs file to pass it in action, however, it only routes to /welcome and it doesn't route to /error. Basically, I just want to see error endpoint or just stop the POST request if validation fails. Please suggest.

> signup.ejs

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>


<% var route = ''; %>
<% if (!messages.error) { %>
<% route = '/welcome' %>
<% }else{ %>
<% route = '/error' %>
<% } %>


<form action="signup<%- route %>" method="post" name="form1">
```

> signup.js

```
router.post('/welcome', function(req, res, next) {

   req.checkBody('name', 'Name cannot be empty').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email', 'Please enter valid email').isEmail();
   req.checkBody('password', 'Password should be more than 5').isLength({ min: 5 });
   req.checkBody('password1', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

   var errors = req.validationErrors();

   if(!errors) {
       var user = {
         name: req.sanitize('name').escape().trim(),
         email: req.sanitize('email').escape().trim(),
         password: req.sanitize('password').escape().trim()
       }
       connection.query('Insert into customers set ?', user, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
           req.flash('error', err);
           //render to signup
           res.redirect('/signup', {
               title: 'Add New User',
               name: user.name,
               email: user.email,
               password: user.password
           })

        }
            req.flash('success', 'Successfully signed up');
            res.render('welcome', {
                title: 'Signed In'
            });

    })
   }else {
    var error_msg = ''

    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        error_msg += error.msg + '<br>'
    })
    req.flash('error', error_msg);
    res.render('signup', {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    })
}
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking.  If you want the end-user to see an error endpoint URL such as `/signup/error` in the browser after an error, then you can just redirect to that URL and create a route on your server for that URL to show the desired error page.

Comment: It also appears that you maybe don't understand what `req.flash()` does.  It sets some state (in a temporary cookie) for the NEXT route that hits your  server.  So, there's no point in doing `req.flash()` followed immediately be `res.render()`.  You would typically follow it with `res.redirect()` and then the redirected URL would have access to the data you set in the `req.flash()`.  Examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/req-flash).

Comment: @jfriend00  Ya i can but what if user is successfully signed up which should route the user to /welcome, I don't know how i can setup two routes in form.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  You can redirect to either `/welcome` or to `/signup/error` depending upon whether there was an error or not.  The form doesn't determine where the user goes next.  The form determines the route that the form data is sent to.  Your server determines what happens after the form is submitted.  You either redirect to a new URL or render a response.